# What is space allocated for NULL values of an Oracle column (especially CLOB)

Tags: oracle, database-design, schema

We have a report (simple text) to store in Oracle , average case will be less than 4K but some cases exceeding that. So an option is to use CLOB.
It is for logging purposes only, not used in query or update. Only insert once and retireve few times.

**Space and overall schema (other tables) performance is of main concern.**

I read about CLOB storage allocation format.

We are contemplating using 2 columns, msgV varchar2(4000) and msgC CLOB. When text exceeds 4k then we store into CLOB otherwise usual varchar2 and CLOB remains NULL.

So my question is,

1. Is this scheme **better w.r.t to above performance consideration** or simply use CLOB ?
   (apart from it entailing more coding work maintaining this condition everywhere)
2. And what is the space consumed by NULL  and Empty CLOBs (or any datatype) ?

Comment: Use a single `CLOB` column. A NULL value does not need space.

Comment: So will the single CLOB column perform (in space and speed) similar to using 2. (defensive way, use bigger only when needed, otherwise safe and usual) ??

Comment: `CLOB`s are *slightly* slower when being retrieved and cannot be indexed. But I would always prefer the cleaner design over something that is trying to optimize a problem that isn't there (yet). If it really turns out to be a problem you can always split the data later.

Comment: You may also want to look into compression options.  Regular table compression can help if you use a VARCHAR2 and there are lot of duplicates.  If you use a CLOB, you may want to look into SecureFiles compression: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#BABIJJHI

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name .  You can actually index clobs.  It doesn't use a BTree index, however you can index it for a full text search. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/cncptdev.htm#CNCPT1537

Answer (score 1):

Use a clob.  If the data in the clob is under 4000 bytes, it will actually be stored inline.  See section in link below about LOB's compared to LONG.

[Oracle Lob](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm)